# Make a button appear selected

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Is there a simple way of making a button appear selected with Swift? I currently have a series of buttons with background images. I want each of the buttons to appear 'selected' once tapped by the user; each button will be used to specify which options the user requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a button appear selected several ways. One is to have a second image which is slightly darker (i.e. looks depressed) and when you set the button's state to `button.selected = true` then the system will automatically use this second image for it's selected state. If you don't have a separate asset (which I wold recommend you do) then you can set `button.userInteractionEnabled = false` which will make it unable to be acted on by the user, as well as change it's alpha component or color or some other property to enforce to the user that the button is no longer selectable.

Answer (score 3):

When you select your button you could change it's state to selected:

```
func buttonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    button.selected = !button.selected
    ...
}
```

And if you want, you could change the background image of your UIButton to have a different image when it's state is selected like this:

```
button.setBackgroundImage(selectedImage, forState: .Selected)
```

This can also be done in Interface Builder:

[image: Change button background image state]